# How to test CanCan's :create using rspec

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test my application's CanCan :create rule. Here is my code:

#### ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    # Admin user
    if user.is_admin?
      can :manage, :all
    end

    # Anyone
    can :read, :all

    # Regular logged in user
    if user.persisted?
      can :create, Comment
      can :create, Node
    end
  end
end
```

#### user_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require "cancan/matchers"

describe User do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(user).to be_valid
  end

  # ...

  describe "abilities" do
    subject(:ability) { Ability.new(user) }
    let(:user) { nil }

    # ...

    context "when is a regular user" do
      let(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

      it "is able to create a new node" do
        should be_able_to(:create, Node.new)
      end

      it "is not able to edit existing node" do
        @node = FactoryGirl.build(:node)
        should_not be_able_to(:update, @node) 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, the above code works fine when i'm testing my application pragmatically but when i'll try to run the tests, it gives me:

```
Failures:

  1) User abilities when is a regular user is able to create a new node
     Failure/Error: should be_able_to(:create, Node.new)
       expected to be able to :create #<Node id: nil, title: nil, body: nil, user_id: nil, thumbnail: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, url: nil, site_id: nil, score: 0, shares_facebook: 0, shares_twitter: 0, status: nil>
```

How can i test this :create method? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the `user` in your spec is not persisted. `FactoryGirl.build` returns a new object but does not save it to the database. So `user.persisted?` will be false in your `Ability`.

The simple fix would be to use `FactoryGirl.create` which does persist the user, though it would make your test a little slower.

Comment: yes, that definitely makes sense and was the reason of this issue. Thanks! :)